# Is Java Swing out of date?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I downloaded Net Beans IDE and created a new desktop aplication. I choose it to be Swing app. The IDE displayed that the Swing framework is out of date and will not be supported in the future.

Does this mean that Swing is out of date? And if so what are the most recent frameworks that can be used to develop desktop applications?

thanks

Comment: Did you choose "Java Desktop Application" as project type?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot on what is the exact message (and what you chose). Btw, what version of netbeans are ou using?

Comment: I don't see it in netbeans 6.8 so I'll go out on a limb and say MS is using 6.9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Swing Application Framework (JSR296) was a project intended to extract the common elements for developing applications with Swing. It is safe to use but is no longer being developed. The official page https://appframework.dev.java.net/ suggests a couple of alternatives, including using the netbeans platform itself and, given how greatly netbeans has matured, I would be keen to investigate this approach.

Swing itself is fine, it'll be around as long as Java is. Though in saying that desktop Java has never really taken hold in the same way other flavours have.

Comment: Yes that's exactly the message. so what shall we do ? stick to swing or find another alternative ?

Comment: SWT/Swing

Or don't make desktops apps in Java :-)

Answer (score 4):

In NetBeans the Desktop Application project type is a project based on an external library that was supposed to be the Swing Application Framework (which does things like session state of GUI controls and resource bundle management) but never matured. So that project type is outdated.

However Swing itself (the GUI platform) is `current' in the sense that it is the foremost GUI toolkit that Java has and will continue to have for some time.

Comment: I see, can you recommend an IDE to develop swing applications ?

Comment: NetBeans is very good for GUI development so stick with that.

Comment: NetBeans has a very nice GUI-editor for Swing.  Some consider it to be the best.

Comment: @Xorty: Swing Application Framework, or SAF for short (JSR I-forget-which) was never finished. It was essentially left in limbo (and contains some serious bugs). To see what I mean you may want to take a look at the Better Swing Application Framework (or any of the other forks out there). 

EDIT: Or are you confusing Netbeans platform with the Swing Application Framework? The Netbeans platform is certainly among the most mature.

Comment: this ? http://it2bug.com/htm/doc/w001/j_swing/p1/f19.htm
It's still in course, don't worry

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK Swing is definitelly not out of date and will be even enhanced in JDK7

Maybe you should show us screenshot, it might be misunderstanding

Answer (score 0):

I think something wrong with your netbeans. Can you show some screenshot?

[The future of swing](http://blogs.oracle.com/theplanetarium/entry/the_future_of_swing)

Comment: lightweight ?! it's one of the heaviest (if not the heaviest) desktop frameworks!

Comment: Sorry, the correct would be it is more lightweight than awt. And I only know swing and awt for Java desktop application as on some sites saying about that : http://mindprod.com/jgloss/swing.html

Comment: awt is long dead. There is also SWT

Comment: oh, I didn't know. When I learnt from my uni, people still say about it. Thanks for your info

Comment: @xorty - Swing is considered lightweight because everything is painted on a canvas, there's very little by the way of OS machinery involved. And regarding AWT, it is only half dead. Swing still requires AWT, but I don't think many people would be targeting AWT for their development.

Comment: @CurtainDog : well, it's bigger performance killer than almost any gui framework. That can't be considered lightweight

Comment: @Xorty: I know what you mean, but in this context lightweight has a different meaning (see, for example, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swing_%28java%29#Configurable)

Comment: @CurtainDog - that's just so painful :(

Comment: Link in answer has moved.